# IE browser to get the cursor position

Tags: php, javascript

This is 2 Written，one for IE,it is wrong,and one for webkit,

I have a textarea,it's id is "web_editor_con2",
I want to make a web editor,when i try to upload picture,
it use "`<form action='./upload.php' method='post' target='file_frame' enctype="multipart/form-data"><iframe name="file_frame" style="display:none;"></iframe>`"

upload.php has the code

```
  echo '<script>
                     if (parent.document.all) {
                    parent.document.getElementById("web_editor_con2").value += "[img=' . $this->conf['SITE'] . "/Public/upload/" . $newpic . '][/img]";
        }else {
            var obj = parent.document.getElementById("web_editor_con2");
            var startPos = obj.selectionStart;
            var endPos = obj.selectionEnd;
             parent.document.getElementById("web_editor_con2").value = obj.value.substring(0, startPos) + "[img=' . $this->conf['SITE'] . "/Public/upload/" . $newpic . '][/img]" + obj.value.substring(endPos);
        }</script>';
```

Can You Have a try to make ie work well?

Comment: Where is the link with the cursor position? It is not clear, please clarify the question.

Comment: And don't forget : Do not write JS code with PHP => bad practice

Comment: for example~I enter "12345",i want to insert a picture link after the 3, like 123[img=http://www.xxxxxx.com/1.jpg][/img]45,in webkit browser it is right,but ie ,i cann't do it

Comment: I recommend to use JQuery to write cross-browser code. Can you?

Comment: is that last website in the world to show example .. even it doesnot have example

Comment: all right,can you look https://github.com/youyax/YouYaX/blob/master/ORG/UBB/ORG/UBB/UploadForEditor.class.php#L42-L44  ,it is no advertisement,Only technical exchanges

Comment: Please improve question.. Its not so clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a jQuery Tutorial that works in Chrome and EI (from what i have tested)

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Example Code from The tutorial:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   }); 
})
</script>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: ok，if i want to export a string ‘123455’  in Coordinate (100,100)，how do it